# Create a new Boolean in a loop, then call it from outside the loop

Tags: java, loops, boolean

everyone. I was hoping that this would be a simple fix, but I can't seem to find anything on it...
I'm writing a simple text-based game, and I have the player come to a set of choices.
Something like:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Boolean loop = true;

    while (loop){
        System.out.println("What do you want to do? [a], or [b]?");
        String choice = reader.readLine();

        if (choice.equals("a")){
            System.out.println("Outcome A");
            System.out.println("Loops back to choice, both A and B available.");
        } else if (choice.equals("b")){
            System.out.println("Outcome B");
            loop = false;
            System.out.println("Story continues, B eventually no longer available.");
        }
    }
```

This works just fine.
My problem comes in where I want to have a new sequence of choices branching from the player's previous choice.
It's difficult for me to explain exactly what I want, but it would go like this:
After choice B, the story goes on, and the player can return to choices A and B somewhere down the line.
But something happens where the player eliminates choice B from being chosen twice.
What I wanted to do was put a new Boolean under choice B, say loop2.
When loop2 = true, I want only choice A to be available, so I basically copy my first loop, but without B being available

My problem is, I can't use the Boolean I put in "loop" in loop2.
I'm VERY rusty with Java and this is sort of an exercise to get me back on my feet.
Would I have to make a separate class to accomplish what I'm trying to do?
Or is there a way to do this just by using a new loop?

I'd appreciate any help, and thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused by the body of your question... but if you want to use a variable outside a loop, you have to declare it outside of that loop....

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was trying to create a new Boolean at the end of B but still inside B, which causes a new loop outside of B. That's not possible, in any way?

Comment: You'll have to start using methods to group logic.

Comment: So I would make something like, public Boolean loop2 if I want to be able to call it from outside the current loop?

Comment: What is your out condition? Or it just have to run eternaly. I understand your problem, I just don't see where you get out of the program. Should it have such an option? Clarifie that so I can create a proper answer to you.

Comment: Oh, this isn't my entire code, just a single loop. More things happen, and the whole thing is basically just println's and a few conditional branches. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "out condition," but this loop breaks for condition B, and there's certain situations (game overs) where the program terminates with `System.exit(0);` That is what you're asking right?

Comment: When you say, `I want only choice A to be available` you mean present to the user the same question (or other one) on the main loop but the user will be unnable to choose B ?

Comment: Yes. Something very close to that. I want this loop to end, and a new loop to begin by using a new Boolean. The new loop will only offer A as a choice after B has been chosen. In my actual code, I have a sort of "hub" location that the player will go to after almost every choice. Choosing certain things will lead to scenarios that won't be repeated (choosing B eliminates B) I don't want to have to rewrite its code after every choice, though, because then I'd have to rewrite all the individual choices as well. Sorry if this is confusing, it's hard for me to explain it well

Comment: Then you will have to use methods, list or array (to store que questions), and list or array to store the answers. Every time you call the method to print a question you have to pass the answers already given, so you can discard that options for the next questions. It will have to be a lot more than the code you did or you wil have to create lots of loops to attend all conditions, questions and options.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Jeroen mentioned methods so I thought just making my Booleans public would work. Thanks for the help, I think I understand how to make this work now

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion, but you can try to use an **array of booleans** for loop variables. For the **first** loop, if user types B , you set that index of the loop array to false, break of that while loop and set the next loop element as true and continue with your algorithm. This *might* require a **nested while loop**, depending on your overall implementation.